# Ticks Label in 3Dplot in Mathematica

Tags: graphics3d

In 3DListPlot, I am plotting data such that I have discretized a contineous function. While plotting, I automatically get the ticks labeling, marking the discrete points. I want to replace the labeling with the labeling of my continuous data, means instead of going from 0 to 1000 points, I want to mark it as going form -5 to 5.

[image: 3DPlot of discrete data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option `DataRange` to specify the actual range of coordinates:

```
ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[i/10 + j/100], {i, 0, 10, 1}, {j, 0, 100, 0.1}]]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[i/10 + j/100], {i, 0, 10, 1}, {j, 0, 100, 0.1}], 
 DataRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 10}}]
```

[image]

Update: you can label the ticks the way you wish using the option `Ticks`:

```
ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[i/10 + j/100], {i, 0, 10, 1}, {j, 0, 100, 0.1}], 
 DataRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 10}}, 
 Ticks -> {{{-5, Row[{-5, Pi/2}]}, {0, Row[{0, Pi/2}]}, {5, Row[{5, Pi/2}]}}, 
         Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: may I ask one more thing? What if I want to add some constant term in ticks label. Means if I want to label ticks as -5X to 5X where X is some constant.

Comment: I tried it. The problem is that if x is say x=Pi/2, then in plot it is automatically multiplying -5 with Pi/2 and plotting in terms of answer. My interest was to show on plot -5x rather than multiplied number.

Comment: @zenith, you can use the option `Ticks`: e.g. with `x` predefined (say `x=10`), add the option `Ticks -> {{{-5, -5 x}, {0, 0 x}, {5, 5 x}}, Automatic, Automatic}` to `Plot3D`. Or, perhaps, something like `Ticks -> {{{-5, Row[{-5, Pi/2}]}, {0, Row[{0, Pi/2}]}, {5, Row[{5, Pi/2}]}},   Automatic, Automatic}`..

Comment: Alright. Let me try this. Thanks again for contentious help.

Comment: Really appreciate for hepling me to solve the problem

Comment: @zenith, glad i could help.